# GDSII stream reading

Tags: physical-design, chip-design

[GDSII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GDSII) is a photomask\artwork format for photolitography. I am having trouble resolving a particular line in the file.

For example,  'SRefs'  means it refers to one of the structures and uses this structure again at new location given by the coordinates and considering corresponding rotation .

How do I resolve the 'ARefs' type of data in GDS II format? What does it mean?

Comment: You have a look at this page: https://boolean.klaasholwerda.nl/interface/bnf/gdsformat.html#rec_aref It looks disgusting, but esentially helped me when implementing a GDS parser.

Answer (score 0):

AREFS are the same as SREFS except the entire array lattice is reflected:

> STRANS [1A01]     Bit array: contains two bytes of bit flags for SREF,
>   AFREF, and text transformation. Bit 0 (leftmost) specifies reflecton.
>   If it is set, then reflection about the X axis is applied before
>   angular rotation. For AREFs, the entire array lattice is reflected,
>   with the individual array elements riidly attached. Bit 13 flags
>   absolute magnification. Bit 14 flags absolute angle. Bit 15
>   (rightmost) and all remaining bits are reserved for future use and
>   must be cleared. If this record is omitted, then the element is
>   assumed to have no reflection and its magnification and angle are
>   assumed to be non-absolute.

Source http://www.artwork.com/gdsii/gdsii/page5.htm

See also this link in the [SPIE Handbook](http://www.cnf.cornell.edu/cnf_spie9.html)